# Does `count` realize a lazy sequence in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Let's say I have a LazySeq

> (def s (take 10 (iterate + 0)))

Does `(count s)` realize the sequence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are asking about lazy sequences, Yes.

```
user> (def s (map #(do (println "doing work") %) (range 4)))
#'user/s
user> (count s)
doing work
doing work
doing work                       
doing work
4
```

Some of the data structures can give you answers in constant time, though lazy sequences do not have a stored count, and **counting always realizes them**.

Comment: the first do isn't necessary

Answer (score 4):

For a LazySeq yes, you can see its count method [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LazySeq.java#L74). It walks every element from head to tail.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the definition of lazy sequence. It's possible to implement ones that know their length without realizing their elements. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471607/how-to-find-length-of-lazy-sequence-without-forcing-realization/18471968#18471968) for an example, but in 99% of the cases they're just LazySeqs so Michiel's answer should cover that.

In your example case it's easy to test, as:

```
(realized? s)
```

returns `true` after calling `(count s)`, so `s` isn't 'clever' enough to know it's length without realizing it's content.

Comment: Oh I did not know about `realized?`. Thanks!